# Create tables and controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create TODO List application.

So I want to create an admin page, and a worker page.

In order to do that, I need two controllers:

```
rails generate controller Admins

rails generate controller Workers
```

now, I want to create two tables and use them in the controllers:

**first table** will be the workers: email (string), full_name (text), is_worker (boolean).

**second table** will be the connection: email_admin(string), email_worker(string), task(text), done (boolean).

how should I define the tables?

I tried:

```
rails generate scaffold workers email: string, full_name: text, is_worker: boolean
rake db:migrate
rails generate scaffold connection email_admin: string, email_worker: string, task: text, done: boolean
rake db:migrate
```

but it defines me controllers of: "workers" and "connection", and I don't want to create controllers, but just tables. (and then I will use the tables in the controllers of: Admins and Workers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rails generate model worker` and `rails generate model connection`. This command will create two models and its correspondent tables.